# Encode video from .NET Bitmaps on the go and stream it live over the internet

Tags: c#, .net, image, streaming, expression-encoder-sdk

Is there a library or method which will allow me to take several Bitmaps in C#, encode them into a video and stream the video live over the internet, possibly using a library like Lidgren.
I am basically taking screen shots of my screen every second and I would like to stream the screen over the internet. I figured that possibly encoding the images into something like H.264 might be a better approach over sending each image's data.

This may or may not be possible... but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you use VNC for this? It is sort of what it was designed for. EDIT - If this is for playback *only* then just use the Justin.TV api and VLC then you don't need to write an application at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [Windows Media Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/screencap.aspx) and [Expression Encoder 4](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoder4_overview.aspx) are for. Is there a reason you don't wish to use them?

Comment: Thanks for that, I've found an Expression Encoder SDK which I'm looking at, hopefully this is exactly what I need! :)