# Create video from images without library or API

Tags: c#, image, screen, recorder

I want to create a screen recorder. To do this, I will be taking a specific amount of screenshots every second and saving them to a temp folder. Once the "recording" has stopped, it will convert these images into a video.

Does anybody know how this is possible - without using external libraries or APIs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without an API... you have a *lot* of code to write.  Good luck.

Comment: Right now, I haven't tried anything for the images to video conversion as I have no idea where to start. I prefer not to use API's or libraries for copyright reasons, but I suppose if you know of one that is completely free to use and distribute, that would be fine.

Comment: API is something, Copyright is something else! simply you cant do this without any API!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251467/how-can-i-create-a-video-from-a-directory-of-images-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958127/encode-video-from-net-bitmaps-on-the-go-and-stream-it-live-over-the-internet